# Regex: Limit the occurrences of numeric characters in an alphanumeric String

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex (for use in java) that would match the following conditions (it's an specific phone format)

1. Can (but not required) start with +
2. Can contain # or -

   - a) List item
   - b) NOT at the START or END of the String
   - c) There cannot be two of consecutive appearances of those
3. Besides +,-,# it can only contain numerical characters and the amount of numerical characters (any number) has to be between 8 to 20.

I know how to do 1), 2a), 2b). Haven't tried 2c yet. But I having serious issues with 3). 
I have been somehow able to limit the appearances of [0-9] but it checks appearances of the same number, and I want to limit the count of any number char.

That attempt was based on: 
[Limit number of alpha characters in regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006994/limit-number-of-alpha-characters-in-regular-expression)

Any ideas are welcomed :)

Comment: Could you please share your regex (as is) and the sample inputs you tried it against?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a look-aheads, this should do it for you:

```
^(?=[^\d\n]*(?:\d[^\d\n]*?){8,20}$)(?!.*[-#][-#])\+?[\d][\d#-]+[\d]$
```

It starts with a positive look ahead that checks for 8-20 repeats of a digit, followed by any number of repeats of non digits. This can optionally be preceded by any number of non digits. That's the verification of number of digits.

Then there's a negative look-ahead to assert there aren't any repeating hyphens or hash signs (captures one followed by a back reference = two in a row).

Finally it allows an optional `+` and after that it's simply a test for any number of repeating digits, hyphens and hash signs.

[Check the examples here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tE3fT0/6).

**Edit:**

Modified regex to handle case 2b, and 2c where one follows directly upon the other (`-#` or `#-`).

Comment: That works perfectly. Thanks for the explanation as well. I was getting confused with the counting of numbers!